# Geomapping using Qlikview BI tool

Tags: qlikview, geomap

I have a dataset with country names (to and from) which is similar to travel starting country and the destination country.
For example: if the travel is between India to Australia then the country origin will be India and the destination will be Australia.

I have collected the latitude and longitude for both origin and destination place.
Now I want to plot the lat and log for origin and destination country using Qlikview tool.

I'm using Qlikview11 Personal edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to achieve this case:

#### 1. Using GeoQlik extension

- Install GeoQlik extension in Qlikview  [Click to Install GeoQlik](http://demo.geoqlik.com/geoqlik/GeoQlikTrial.qar)
- Open GeoQlik extension in Webmode and choose Line Graph.
- Add the dimensions as Country Origin and Country Destination
- Add the lat and log positions as in below image.
  [image]

  Similarly you can do it for Country Destination.
  You can also adjust the line width and color properties also.

Demerit: In GeoQlik trial version, you cant able to save the visualizations.(need to be licensed version to enjoy all the features)

#### 2. Using Line Graph

Ref from : http://qvdesign.wordpress.com/2012/06/22/new-qlikview-chart-type-dynamic-network-flow-charts/

They used static image of world map as background. They created a line graph with X and Y coordinates running axes from 0 to 200 and set as transparent.

Here the fuzzy thing is I don't know how they calculated lat and long positions!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Qlikview Mapping Extension that installs with the product. See the "Extension Examples.qvw" in the installed examples. Note the instruction on the first sheet that directs you to complete the installation by launching the .qar file. In the Extension Examples is a sample showing how to plot lines and points on a map.